# XCode still indicates a build is running when it isn't

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ide, ios-simulator

I'm not sure if I phrased the question properly but I'm getting strange XCode build and run behavior that is frankly too annoying to ignore anymore.

Here's my scenario:

I build and run my XCode project onto my iPhone to play around with. Then I click the square stop button in the toolbar which terminates the app on my device and the stop button turns light grey again. This is then what I see:

[image]

I edit some code and then hit play again. Hmm, that's weird, it's not building. Taking a look at the above screenshot I see that even though it looks like it stopped running it still says "running" in the activity viewer. Expanding the little "2" button shows me this:

[image]

So that's the problem. I don't know why when I hit stop, everything stops as normal but it still says "running" and isn't starting up again when I hit run again. Now here is the annoying solution I'm working with. To get it running again, first I expand the scheme menu and choose a random simulator device like so:

[image]

Then, I simply switch it back to my device like so:

[image]

After I do that, the activity viewer automatically starts building the project and launching it on my device as if everything was normal:

[image]

It does this almost every time I build and run. It didn't used to do this at all and frankly my patience has run out with it. Am I missing something? How does one solve this without my hack-around? F.Y.I. I'm using XCode 7.1 (7B91b).

Comment: Weird. I would recommend that you log a question on either the Apple Developer forums or a bug with Apple at: https://bugreport.apple.com . You already have a question and a reproducible case. You might want to add details of all the hardware and os versions plus other environment info (like if you're running under a standard account or an admin account and any third-party software that could interfere with the USB connection etc..)

Comment: Disconnect your iDevice from your Mac maybe? I saw that if you're running a test app and that your Mac goes into screensaver mode, XCode has a weird behavior. Disconnecting the iDevice stops the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem using Xcode 7.1 (7B91b). Happens pretty much any time I terminate after an exception. Restarting Xcode works. Will also file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, i just build the project once when the running condition is showing up and thats it it solves my issue. So i would suggest just ⌘B once.